# php sql delete button

Tags: php, sql, button, sql-delete

I'm trying to make a delete button from sql. I started a function called $del but I don't know how to complete it, in the form of a delete button echoe'd out beside the current echo statements.

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("database", $con);
$sql = "INSERT INTO camps (city, map, park, day, details) 
    VALUES ('$_POST[city]','$_POST[map]','$_POST[park]','$_POST[day]','$_POST[details]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

$number = 0;
$del = mysql_query("DELETE FROM camps WHERE user_id= '$number'");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM camps");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<a href=\"'" . $row['map'] . "\">" . $row['city'] . "</a>";
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to make your links pass a param to a script that will delete that record.
Your links would looks something like this

```
 echo "<a href=\"'delete.php?id=" . $user_id"\">" . $row['city'] . "</a>";
```

Then your delete can just grab the params from the $_GET gloabal, and pass them into your sql like so

```
  $del = mysql_query("DELETE FROM camps WHERE user_id=" . $_GET['user_id']);
```

This current query will delete all camps for that user (adjust params / sql as needbe).

However, you should NEVER pass user vars into your sql strings. You leave yourself open for [sql injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). I would recommend using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to escape your sql. I would also recommend using the post method for any destructive db operation so that you don't accidentally alter something.