# Couldn't find variable from multiple pages

Tags: php, mysql

I'm so confused and yeah everything will be on database. And, it's really somewhat deep. There are 4 pages of PHP concerned for this problem. First of all, I need to explain and you need to know the site map. The site map would be like this **forum.php** --> **forum-topic** --> **discussion.php** --> **deleteTopic.php**.

So, I'm going to explain more clearly as shown as below.

*Discussion.php*. This page is used to go a new page to delete the topic. Therefore, I'm passing this variable like **topic_id** to *deleteTopic.php* because I have to retrieve the value from *discussion.php*. And something like this below.

```
<a href=\"deleteTopic.php?topic_id=$topic_id\">DELETE</a>
```

*DeleteTopic.php*. This page is used to delete the chosen topic and retrieve the **topic_id** from *discussion.php*.

```
$topic_id = $_REQUEST['topic_id'];    
$sql = "DELETE FROM forum_topic WHERE topic_id = $topic_id ";
mysql_query($sql);
echo "Topic has been deleted!";
header ('Location:forum-topic.php');
exit();
?>
```

And yes, it is successfully deleted the chosen topic, but it shows some errors on *forum-topic.php* like **unidentified thread_id and thread_name**. I am realised that I have retrieved that value in *forum.php*. Because in *deleteTopic.php*, it has a value from *forum.php*. So the code would be like this.

*Forum.php*. This is where the chosen thread going to *forum-topic.php*. Therefore, I have to pass variable like thread_id and thread_name.

```
<a href=\"forum-topic.php?thread_id=$thread_id&thread_name=$thread_name\">$thread_name</a>
```

So, can you please tell what should I do with this? I don't know where I should retrieve and passing variables from *discussion.php* to *deleteTopic.php* and navigate to *forum-topic.php* after successfully deleted the chosen topic. Unfortunately, *forum-topic.php* has some values from *forum.php*.

So, can you tell me where should I start? And also can you lead me there? I am really appreciate for any answers from you. Cheers!

Comment: As per your other question that was solved earlier, you're using `mysql_query($sql);` notice the `mysql_` instead of `mysqli`? So, if that's the case with this one again and that you're using the same DB connection as the other (which you should), you'd need to do `mysqli_query($conn,$sql);`

Comment: Yes, I was trying to convert from MySql to MySqli, I was trying to expand my knowledge since i've been left out for too long.

Comment: And is it working for you now?

Comment: No, it's not working yet, im still trying to do it. And will let you and other knows.

Comment: Have a look at these Q&A's on SO that could be of help. Some are `mysql_` but that can easily be modified http://stackoverflow.com/q/13997358/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/21359041/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/21048004/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/20603973/

Comment: great!!! but i've seen them all before I posted these questions :) Thanks for sharing!

Comment: You're welcome. They're the ones I already keep on files on my PC for references.

Comment: I see, could you give an answer for this question? I know this would be hard but i've done to convert from mysql into mysql and only this problem left.

Comment: You wrote in [`"this comment"`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21470920/couldnt-find-variable-from-multiple-pages?noredirect=1#comment32420961_21471298) that it works now, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store the values of thread_id and name, store it in a [session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php) and retrieve them whenever you want to.

So, in forum-topic.php, first check if you have new thread variables, and add them to the session, else, if you are coming from deleteTopic.php, you can use the existing thread variables from the session.
The general idea is something like this-

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_GET['thread_id']) && isset($_GET['thread_name'])){
        //If the GET parameters are available. Store them.
        $_SESSION['thread_id'] = rawurldecode($_GET['thread_id']);
        $_SESSION['thread_name'] = rawurldecode($_GET['thread_name']);
    }else{
        if(!isset($_SESSION['thread_id']) && !isset($_SESSION['thread_name'])){
            //Error.
            die('error');   //Or you can redirect.
        }
    }
    /*
    The session variables have been initialised.
    */
    $t_id   = $_SESSION['thread_id'];
    $t_name = $_SESSION['thread_name'];
    /*
        From here on, instead of using $_GET['thread_id'] and $_GET['thread_name'], use $t_id and $t_name.
    */
    //Rest of your code.
?>
```

The main problem is with the handling of the parameters when you return after deleting from the table and persisting of the thread variables.

Comment: May I know where I should code that? Is that in forum.php? or where? And where should I start session? Is it in forum-topic? or where? Can you explain a little bit clearly? I understand what you are saying but I just don't know where I should locate them into. Thanks!

Comment: The code is for forum-topic.php. This code should be on the top because you are ascertaining if you should display the page or not(depending on the thread vars). You need to use session for all the pages where you need thread variables to persist.

Comment: In this case, it should be okay if you use session_start() only on forum-topic page, since you are accessing session variables only here.

Comment: I tried to use this code to put in forum-topic.php, it is not working at all. do I need to put echo inside control? @Yeah

Comment: And can you try to give an example inside `/* */` ?

Comment: I have elaborated a lot in the edit. The problem is that after you return from deleteTopic.php, you are not passing the GET vars, so, that cannot be used in forum-topic.php as is. Storing the thread vars allows to use those vars again, when forum-topic.php is re-entered.

Comment: Works now for me. Thanks. However, there is something I want to ask about. What if in forum-topic has session like *thread_name* and *thread_id*, **but in discussion.php** i need another session again like *topic_id* and *topic_name*. So, if I typed `session_start();` every pages. It will get crashed if i have two sessions. What should I do if i want to make 2 sessions?

Comment: For all the pages (under the same directory) a single session is maintained, and its id is stored in the form of a cookie for persist ance . So at the top of dicussion.php session_start will tap into existing session and wont crash. Infact u can even access thread vars from there.

Answer (score 0):

Add logic to forum-topic.php to gracefully handle not receiving any parameters, or even receiving invalid values for thread_id and thread_name. There should be some default defined as a fall back.

You could also make use of session variables to handle remembering values between pages. If you haven't used them before the php.net docs may seem a little intimidating at first, but if you search for some examples they can be surprisingly simple to use.

Then *please* read up on [SQL Injection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and remove the ability for the user to change $topic_id to whatever they want in the URL to either attack your database or just delete arbitrary topics.

Also strongly consider changing all your mysql functions to mysqli or PDO because the mysql functions are deprecated. (PDO and mysqli also provide better ways of protecting against SQL injection using parameterized queries.)

Sorry I don't have a quick and easy answer for you, but all this will go a long way towards improving your code going forward.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `isset()` function to see if variables have values:

```
if (isset($thread_id) && isset($thread_name)){
echo "<a href=\"forum-topic.php?thread_id=$thread_id&thread_name=$thread_name\">$thread_name</a>"; }
```

Comment: By the way, your `echo` lacks starting and ending quotes and will throw a parse error.

Comment: oops, i forgot to put them.